# Add canvas app to layout of all object

Tags: sobject, related-list, canvas, page-layout

How can we add connected canvas app to layout of all the objects like account, opportunity, custom objects etc.

Currently I have to go to each object, edit layout and add canvas app.

Also, If possible can I show canvas app under related list.

Thanks in advance.I am new to salesforce environment.

Answer (score 0):

First, the UI only allows editing one layout at a time. You could use some sort sort of metadata tool to mass update the layouts, but you'd still need a way to edit all the xml files that'd have to be modified.

Secondly, canvas apps can't be added anywhere you like. I'd love to see the ability to add canvas apps and Visualforce pages as related lists, but that simply isn't possible today.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Canvas (from within a VF page) and in a suitable Section under each page layout.

i.e. Account detail page layout -> Add a section -> Add the VF page, which is holding your Canvas.

If you want to do the same in bulk manner, you need to do once for one page layout and extract the meta-data XML ...  refer the same structure and add the Canvas section similarly in all other page layouts in their respective Meta-data XML  and save it back to SFDC server.

I would believe, drag, n drop of Canvas section on each page layout is still relatively easier and safer option.